# receive messy data on raspberry pi using lora

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, lora

I have 2 lora-ra02 (SX1278) module to send/receive data. Sending side using STM32f103C8t6 and receiving side using Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

> STM32f103C8T6 --> LORA-RA02 <-------> LORA-RA02 --> RASPBERRY PI 3 B+

Now, I send "Hello" from STM32 to Raspberry, But I get messy word unfortunately.

This is my codes: STM32 Code on ARDUINO IDE:

```
/*
   LoRaLib Transmit Example

   This example transmits LoRa packets with one second delays
   between them. Each packet contains up to 256 bytes
   of data, in the form of:
    - Arduino String
    - null-terminated char array (C-string)
    - arbitrary binary data (byte array)

   For more detailed information, see the LoRaLib Wiki
   https://github.com/jgromes/LoRaLib/wiki

   For full API reference, see the GitHub Pages
   https://jgromes.github.io/LoRaLib/
*/

// include the library
#include <LoRaLib.h>

// create instance of LoRa class using SX1278 module
// this pinout corresponds to RadioShield
// https://github.com/jgromes/RadioShield
// NSS pin:   10 (4 on ESP32/ESP8266 boards)
// DIO0 pin:  2
// DIO1 pin:  3
SX1278 lora = new LoRa;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // initialize SX1278 with default settings
  Serial.print(F("Initializing ... "));
  // carrier frequency:           434.0 MHz
  // bandwidth:                   125.0 kHz
  // spreading factor:            9
  // coding rate:                 7
  // sync word:                   0x12
  // output power:                17 dBm
  // current limit:               100 mA
  // preamble length:             8 symbols
  // amplifier gain:              0 (automatic gain control)
  int state = lora.begin();
  if (state == ERR_NONE) {
    Serial.println(F("success!"));
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("failed, code "));
    Serial.println(state);
    while (true);
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(F("Sending packet ... "));

  // you can transmit C-string or Arduino string up to
  // 256 characters long
  // NOTE: transmit() is a blocking method!
  //       See example TransmitInterrupt for details
  //       on non-blocking transmission method.
  int state = lora.transmit("Hello");

  // you can also transmit byte array up to 256 bytes long
  /*
    size_t len = 8;
    byte byteArr[len] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x56,
                         0x78, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF};
    int state = lora.transmit(byteArr, len);
  */

  if (state == ERR_NONE) {
    // the packet was successfully transmitted
    Serial.println(F(" success!"));

    // print measured data rate
    Serial.print(F("Datarate:\t"));
    Serial.print(lora.getDataRate());
    Serial.println(F(" bps"));

  } else if (state == ERR_PACKET_TOO_LONG) {
    // the supplied packet was longer than 256 bytes
    Serial.println(F(" too long!"));

  } else if (state == ERR_TX_TIMEOUT) {
    // timeout occurred while transmitting packet
    Serial.println(F(" timeout!"));

  }

  // wait a second before transmitting again
  delay(1000);
}
```

and this is Raspberry Pi code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

""" This program sends a response whenever it receives the "INF" """

# Copyright 2018 Rui Silva.
#
# This file is part of rpsreal/pySX127x, fork of mayeranalytics/pySX127x.
#
# pySX127x is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public
# License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later
# version.
#
# pySX127x is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
#
# You can be released from the requirements of the license by obtaining a commercial license. Such a license is
# mandatory as soon as you develop commercial activities involving pySX127x without disclosing the source code of your
# own applications, or shipping pySX127x with a closed source product.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with pySX127.  If not, see
# <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import time
from SX127x.LoRa import *
#from SX127x.LoRaArgumentParser import LoRaArgumentParser
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD

BOARD.setup()
BOARD.reset()
#parser = LoRaArgumentParser("Lora tester")


class mylora(LoRa):
    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(mylora, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)

    def on_rx_done(self):
        BOARD.led_on()
        print("\nRxDone")
        self.clear_irq_flags(RxDone=1)
        payload = self.read_payload(nocheck=True)
        print ("Received: ")
        mens=bytes(payload).decode("utf-8", 'ignore')
        print(mens)
        BOARD.led_off()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)

    def on_tx_done(self):
        print("\nTxDone")
        print(self.get_irq_flags())

    def on_cad_done(self):
        print("\non_CadDone")
        print(self.get_irq_flags())

    def on_rx_timeout(self):
        print("\non_RxTimeout")
        print(self.get_irq_flags())

    def on_valid_header(self):
        print("\non_ValidHeader")
        print(self.get_irq_flags())

    def on_payload_crc_error(self):
        print("\non_PayloadCrcError")
        print(self.get_irq_flags())

    def on_fhss_change_channel(self):
        print("\non_FhssChangeChannel")
        print(self.get_irq_flags())

    def start(self):
        while True:
            self.reset_ptr_rx()
            self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT) # Receiver mode
            while True:
                pass;


lora = mylora(verbose=True)
#args = parser.parse_args(lora) # configs in LoRaArgumentParser.py

#     Slow+long range  Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/8, Sf = 4096chips/symbol, CRC on. 13 dBm
lora.set_pa_config(pa_select=1, max_power=21, output_power=17)
lora.set_bw(BW.BW125)
lora.set_coding_rate(CODING_RATE.CR4_7)
lora.set_spreading_factor(9)
lora.set_rx_crc(True)
lora.set_low_data_rate_optim(True)
print (lora.get_version())
#  Medium Range  Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/5, Sf = 128chips/symbol, CRC on 13 dBm
#lora.set_pa_config(pa_select=1)

assert(lora.get_agc_auto_on() == 1)

try:
    print("START lora")
    lora.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print("Exit")
    sys.stderr.write("KeyboardInterrupt\n")
finally:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print("Exit")
    lora.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
BOARD.teardown()
```

This is output of running code on Raspberry Pi (Receiver):

[Output on Raspberry Pi 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBJrB.png)

So, Now I do not know where is my problem, and what should I do?
Any suggestion?

Comment: I have not knowledge of LoRa and the modules you are using, but I saw that you decode the received text as utf-8 but sending a c-string witch is usually ascii. If the STM c-compiler does not work with utf-8 coded string literals, this could be the problem.

Comment: But I am newbie, and do not know how should I change that? In fact, What will be be the correct syntax in send/receive part?

Comment: My idea was, that you probably have decoding problems. i.e you might send bytes decoded in the ASCII character set from the STM32 to the Raspi. On the Raspi you receive these bytes and interpret them as utf-8 characters. This is done in the method `def on_rx_done(self):` in line `mens=bytes(payload).decode("utf-8", 'ignore')`. You can check if I am right if you change utf-8 to ascii. `mens=bytes(payload).decode("ascii", 'ignore')`.

Comment: Thanks for answering me Peter, I changed to code as you told, `mens=bytes(payload).decode("ascii", 'ignore')`. but problem not solved yet ...

Comment: Then I was wrong. I'm sorry but then there so many possibilities  that might cause this problem. And as I said I'm not familiar with LoRa nor am I a python guru. I'm afraid I can not help you any further. but I up voted you question hoping someone with more and better skills can help you. If you will find a solution, I'd be pretty interested. ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much dear Peter, i am working on Lora variables such as: spreading factor, frequency, preamble length and ..., maybe the problem is not on the python code and syntax.

Comment: IMHO, the fact that you receive **different** data at each attempt despite transmitting an unchanging value suggests it is not a systematic error of decoding but more likely a timing/transmission error.

Comment: So, What is your solution? you mean I should check setting and spreading factor of Lora?

Comment: can i suggest you something, try to use this library for you raspberry pi "raspi_lora" https://pypi.org/project/raspi-lora/, the reason is it worked for me, i tried the one you are using and it didn't work for me, you me get lucky to receive data despite the error. and keep in mind to use the right configuration, set the SF, the CR, the frequency and the BW, i used 868.1 (which is channel 0) with SF=7 and BW=125 and CR=4/5. by they way, be careful of the duty cycle (it's 1% in my case), check your region so you know the right frequency and the right duty cycle.

Comment: duty cycle tell you how many second you can use the band. to save you many calculations send a message after 2 min and 11 sec. ( for now just play it carefully because you are doing some test) later when you will do some LoraWan projects you need to keep those things in mind. and about the utf-8 or ascii, i didn't worry about that in my test when i used raspi-lora, i didn't even need to tell which decode i need to use, you are sending data in byte after all.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, just FYI: UTF-8 uses ASCII-encoding for basic ASCII characters. This means that any 7 bits ASCII character (character codes up to hexadecimal 0x7F or binary %01111111) is encoded exactly the same way in both ASCII and UTF-8. (Still then, one should indeed not send/expect UTF-8 with LoRa; one should not even send ASCII or any text at all, as that's just a waste of the very limited maximum LoRa payload sizes.)

Comment: As SF9 is not a low data rate, you might want to try with `lora.set_low_data_rate_optim(False)` (Maybe using `True` enables it only when needed, but if that always enables it then that's not good for SF9: for 125 KHz it should only be enabled for SF11 and SF12.) Also, I'd try with different texts, to see what that gives you. (Things like `Helg1gM` might make you think you get the first 3 characters for `Hello`, but maybe that's not the case.) Finally: please don't include basic terminal output as an image.

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for this issue. In my PI, the frequency was set to 434 not 433! Check that with the API : ]